# Using value from foreach loop in output

Tags: php

Perhaps this is a very basic question, but I couldn't find any appropriate answer after Googling, and I'm quite new to this. How can I parse the value from a PHP foreach loop into a url and make it a query string?

Sounds unclear? Let me explain.

So, here's my PHP code:

```
<?php foreach ($results as $data){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $data->emp_id; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data->emp_name; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data->emp_mobile_no; ?></td>
        <td><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin_logins/employee3"><button id="button_edit">Edit</button></a></td>
        <td><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin_logins/employee4"><button id="button_delete">Delete</button></a></td>
    </tr>
<?php }?>
```

Now, what I want to do is something like this:

```
 <td><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin_logins/employee3/value of $data->emp_id"><button id="button_edit">Edit</button></a></td>
```

And, similarly, this as well:

```
 <td><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin_logins/employee4/value of $data->emp_id"><button id="button_delete">Delete</button></a></td>
```

Now, what's the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use below code:

```html
<?php foreach ($results as $data){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $data->emp_id; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data->emp_name; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data->emp_mobile_no; ?></td>
        <td><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin_logins/employee3/<?php echo $data->emp_id; ?>"><button id="button_edit">Edit</button></a></td>
        <td><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin_logins/employee4/<?php echo $data->emp_id; ?>"><button id="button_delete">Delete</button></a></td>
    </tr>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @hardik. I didn't know this syntax previously. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @CrescentMoon glad to helping you... :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it with heredoc to make it easier to look at:

```
<?php
foreach ($results as $data) {
    $base_url = base_url();
    echo <<<TABLEROW
        <tr>
            <td>{$data->emp_id}</td>
            <td>{$data->emp_name}</td>
            <td>{$data->emp_mobile_no}</td>
            <td><a href="{$base_url}index.php/admin_logins/employee3/{$data->emp_id}"><button id="button_edit">Edit</button></a></td>
            <td><a href="{$base_url}index.php/admin_logins/employee4/{$data->emp_id}"><button id="button_delete">Delete</button></a></td>
        </tr>

    TABLEROW;
}
?>
```

Comment: +1 Completely forgot about heredoc. It's another nice way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

What you want is to pass the `ID` from view to your `controller`. This should use help:

On your view:

```
<?php foreach ($results as $data){ ?>
    <tr>
        ...
        <td><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin_logins/employee/edit?id={$data->emp_id}"><button id="button_edit">Edit</button></a></td>
        ...
    </tr>
<?php }?>
```

On your controller `employee`:

```
function edit($id = NULL)
{
    if(is_null($id))
        exit('Invalid employee id');

    $this->load->model('employee_model', 'employee');

    $employee = $this->employee->read($id);

    //do your stuff here
}
```

On your model `employee_model':

```
function read($id = NULL)
{    
    return $this->db->where('emp_id', $id)
                     ->get('employee')->row_array();
}
```